# '/api/' routing isn't working with Nginx, ExpressJS and NextJS

Tags: node.js, api, nginx, server, next.js

I am having a Nextjs frontend running at port 3000. It is proxied to port 8080 of domain wowp.online. If you go you will see the NextJS frontend there.

Then I have another ExpressJS app running at port 5002 to proxied to 8080 of wowp.online/api.

The NextJS app routes are working fine. But the Express backend endpoints are not accessible. The backend app is running and only showing up on the root page. For example https://wowp.online/api/v1/users is showing the content from https://wowp.online/api/v1/

My routes of backend

```
//routes
app.use('/v1/themes', themeRoutes);
app.use('/v1/uploads', uploadRoutes);
app.use('/v1/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/v1/admin', adminRoutes);

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'fail',
    message: 'Root page of api is not available'
  });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).json({ empty: 'You mistakenly came to mars???' });
});
```

My Nginx config,

```
server {

        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name wowp.online www.wowp.online;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/wowp.online.log;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5002;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        }


        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked into using Next's [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) function? You might be able to have Next rewrite incoming requests matching the pattern `/api/v1/:path*` to point to your Express routes, e.g., `https://wowp.online:5002/api/v1/:path*` (or whichever port Express is really on... your setup is a little confusing because of all the proxies between 3000, 5002, 8080 so not sure which is assigned to Next or to Express or both at the same time causing a conflict?)

Comment: I did that, still doesn't work

Comment: Pls how did you solve this issue?, am also facing this problem  @AbuSayeedMondal

Comment: Is it the same? I don't remember how it worked.